# what will be value of limit if function is not defined

Tags: limits

if f(x) is not defined in neighborhood of x=a then what will be limit of f(x) at x=a.

what I know is if f(x) is not approaching fixed value then limit is DNE, but what if function is not defined. Lets say a function f(x) is defined in (-infinity, a) and we want to find RHL for f(x) at x=a then what will be the ans will it be 
"we can not find as function is not defined"
or
"DNE"
or
"undefined"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $f$ is not defined on a neighborhood of $x=a$, then the limit $$\lim_{x\to a} f(x)$$ is also not defined.

Comment: thanks dear 5xum. So answer of limit will be undefined and will not be DNE, is this statement correct?

Comment: @golushailuoo7 I would say so, yes.

Comment: @thanks 5xum to clear my doubt :), be happy !!!

Comment: I would say otherwise. Let's consider the function $f(x) = x$ for $x \in (0, \infty)$. Then $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} f(x)$ is equal to $0$ by the epsilon delta criterion, even though $f(x)$ itself is not defined at $x = 0$.